# How to write singlets and triplets in second quantization for fermions?

Tags: fermions, second-quantization

It has been a long time I haven't done this and I am having a hard time writing things down in second quantization notation. Let us have a $n$-body system where the spin part and orbital parts are decoupled.

If want to write a two particle state, let's say a triplet state $\alpha$, with parallel spins, an electron with energy $\epsilon_1$ and another with $\epsilon_2$, I would write something like 
$$|\alpha\rangle=c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c^\dagger_{2\uparrow}|\emptyset\rangle$$
where $|\emptyset\rangle$ is the void state, and $\uparrow,\downarrow$ are the spin states.

Same for a singlet $\beta$ with two electrons in the same energy
$$|\beta\rangle=c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c^\dagger_{1\downarrow}|\emptyset\rangle$$

But how do I distinguish a state $\gamma$  with $m_z=0$ (different energies, opposite spins)? What does this do?
$$|\gamma\rangle=c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c^\dagger_{2\downarrow}|\emptyset\rangle$$
This could be either a triplet (with opposite spins) or a singlet, what am I missing?

Edit: I now realize that there has to be a difference in the Fock space, between writing $|n_{1\uparrow},n_{1\downarrow},n_{2\uparrow},n_{2\downarrow}\rangle=|1001\rangle$ and $|0,1,1,0\rangle$ but I don't know how to interpret these states in terms of the singlet and the unparalleled triplet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the wavefunction is symmetric in spin for the triplet and antisymmetric for the singlet. So in your notation, the triplet is
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}(c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c^\dagger_{2\downarrow} + c^\dagger_{1\downarrow}c^\dagger_{2\uparrow})|\emptyset\rangle$$
and the singlet is
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}(c^\dagger_{1\uparrow}c^\dagger_{2\downarrow} - c^\dagger_{1\downarrow}c^\dagger_{2\uparrow})|\emptyset\rangle.$$

Comment: Why is not the other way around?

Comment: @Mauricio Why do you think it's the other way around?

Comment: You are telling me to check on the a/symmetry of the spin part and not the orbital part, why is that?

Comment: @Mauricio Because you were asking about whether something is a spin singlet or spin triplet. That has nothing to do with the orbital behavior, you can infer it from the spins alone.

Comment: @Mauricio Meanwhile, the total wavefunction (spin plus orbital) is automatically antisymmetric -- that's the whole point of using second quantization notation, of course.

Comment: I am having a hard time to see why the singlet and triplet that you wrote have signs that mirror the symmetries of the spin parts in first quantization